# Flutter app resizing on different devices

Tags: flutter, autoresize

I installed my app on 2 different devices, the problem is both devices show different widget sizes. Both devices have different screen sizes.

1. The expected result ->
   image1 from Moto One Fusion+

[image]

2. image2 from OnePlus 6pro

[image]

main.dart code ->

```
void main() {
  runApp(BmiApp());
}

class BmiApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const BmiApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/input': (context) => InputPage(),
        '/calculate': (context) => CalculatedResult(),
      },
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          color: Color(0xFF0A1234),
        ),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A1234),
      ),
      initialRoute: '/input',
    );
  }
}
```

input_page.dart code ->

```
class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const InputPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InputPage> createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('BMI Calculator'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body:Column(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Inside column I have stacked all the widgets.
[Github link for complete code](https://github.com/Rahul-Rasve/BMI-Calculator/blob/master/lib/input_page.dart)

Comment: if you like to provide fixed size you can wrap the widget with `SizedBox` provide hard-coded value(not recommended)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh No, I want it to adapt to different screen sizes.

Comment: You can use layout Builder or Flexible widget, remove those fixed sizes

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Layout builder takes solid parameters as input I guess, but I don't have much idea about Flexible Widget, although Flexible widget seems a better solution for my problem. My question is, will it automatically adapt to the screen size(Flexible widgets)?

Comment: yap, It will adapt the parent widget size& maintain the ratio